# ".app" added after app name in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I found very strange bug in ios, when I want to change my appName into xxxx.l, app name in phone shows xxxx.l.app, but if I change to xxxx.x everything is fine. Any ideas how remove ".app" from appName?

There is a similar problem but not solved:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/12783

Comment: as the name of the app, you mean the "bundle identifier" ?  [try checking the .plist file in the "Executable file" field]

Comment: No, app name: Bundle display name and Bundle Name in info.plist

Comment: .pl is a top level domain. You might confuse users into thinking it's a web shortcut, so iOS might be adding .app for you so user isn't confused.

Comment: @MarcusAdams may be but ".i", ".l" also working the same, add .app after app name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

Looks like new iOS9 fix this bug, now everything is ok